# PowerShell remote call. Access is denied

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

In order to automate test releases, I need access to remote computer in other domain group.
What I've done on remote computer:

1. run Enable-PSRemoting
2. set TrustedHosts "*"
3. added https listener with self-signed certificate
4. opened 5985 and 5986 ports

So now scripts are running successfuly via PowerShell console.
But when I'm trying to run remote script via TeamCity agent I've been receiving following error:

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
Access is denied. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

TeamCity agent service is running with Local System rights.

Session initialization

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $appServerPwd -AsPlainText -Force 
$appCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($appServerUser,$password)
$rs = New-PSSession -ComputerName $appServer -Credential $appCred -UseSSL -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck) -Authentication Negotiate
```

Also when I'm trying to make remote call to domain computer via TeamCity everything works.
Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Dima

Comment: Remote computer is running under Windows Server 2003 and the client under Vista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem, as soon I changed "Local System" user to Administrator user on TeamCity agent service, everything started to work. 
So the issues was in rights (starting PSSesion) between "Local System" and Administrator.

Comment: Whilst this workaround may work it is worth noting granting services local admin rights is generally a bad thing.